# Trying to delete character in TOC deletes entire TOC line

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an ebook that I store and edit in MS Word (2019). I often add new chapters. When I do so, I update the TOC.

But I also have pictures at the beginning of the chapter headers, so the when the reader clicks on a chapter name in the TOC and goes to the chapter, they see the picture first, then scroll down to the chapter header text.

When I update the TOC, all those pictures are copied to the new TOC. Then I go through and delete them. Right after each picture is a character that must be deleted too; sometimes it's a carriage return, sometimes a space character.

I wrote this Word VBA code to try to automate it. It works fine to delete the pictures. But then when it tries to delete the character after the picture, it deletes the entire TOC line -- the whole TOC entry.

I tried turning the macro recorder on while manually deleting the characters. It recorded exactly what I have below to delete the characters, but which when run in VBA against characters in the TOC it actually deletes the entire line.

Also, this would be safer if I could detect whether the cursor was within the TOC, rather than relying on hard-coded counts of how many pictures are before the TOC and how many are within the TOC.

Here's what I have:

```
Const NUM_SHAPES_BEFORE_FIRST_TOC_PICTURE_TO_DELETE As Long = 2    
Const NUM_SHAPES_IN_TOC_TO_DELETE As Long = 27    

Const ASCII_CARRIAGE_RETURN As Long = 13    
Const ASCII_SPACE As Long = 32    

Sub DeleteTocPictures()

    Dim iDeletePic As Long, iPicCount As Long, iFirstPicToDelete As Long, iLastPicToDelete As Long    
    Dim iPicsDeletedCount As Long    
    Dim iAsciiNextChar As Long   

    iPicCount = ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count    
    iFirstPicToDelete = NUM_SHAPES_BEFORE_FIRST_TOC_PICTURE_TO_DELETE + 1    
    iLastPicToDelete = NUM_SHAPES_IN_TOC_TO_DELETE + NUM_SHAPES_BEFORE_FIRST_TOC_PICTURE_TO_DELETE

    iPicsDeletedCount = 0 'init.    
    For iDeletePic = iFirstPicToDelete To iLastPicToDelete    
        DoEvents    
        ThisDocument.InlineShapes(iFirstPicToDelete).Select: DoEvents    
        ThisDocument.InlineShapes(iFirstPicToDelete).Delete 'not iDeletePic here, because the shapes' index numbers change each time one is deleted.

        iAsciiNextChar = Asc(Selection.Characters(1).Text)    
        If iAsciiNextChar = ASCII_CARRIAGE_RETURN Then    
            'press delete key TWICE for carriage return character.    
            Stop    
'            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2    
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1    
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1    
            Stop    
        ElseIf iAsciiNextChar = ASCII_SPACE Then    
            'press delete key ONCE for space character.    
            Stop    
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1    
            Stop    
        End If   

        iPicsDeletedCount = iPicsDeletedCount + 1    
'        Stop    
    Next iDeletePic

    MsgBox "Pictures deleted: " & iPicsDeletedCount

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cross-posted *and answered before posting here*, at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_o365b/in-word-vba-how-can-i-delete-pictures-from-the-toc/b65ae45c-2beb-4e58-8a07-22a830b0a7de?messageId=6e2e81c5-edd2-413b-8ac1-4f6b29626a28. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Sorry, I'll note cross-posts after this. 

At the time I posted here, I had only seen the first answer at answers dot ms, which I didn't find helpful.